# Как отобразить 3D модель на сайте (Obj файл)

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl, obj

Необходимо отобразить 3D модель (OBJ файл ) на сайте, с возможностью накладывать текстуры через элементы управления (Конструктор одежды)

Вот пример дизайна: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/07/08/0010/1583/693807/07/0ef31b8c7c.jpg

Поджскажите какие то может решения есть, на js?

Comment: Что мешает заглянуть в примеры по Three.js и посмотреть там? Например, вот здесь: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=obj#webgl_loader_obj_mtl